# How to Send message to google hangout using google + api in C#.net?

Tags: c#, google-plus

By following the steps given in this link https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp, google plus automatically sign in with the help of gplus-quickstart-csharp code provided in that link.
**Now i want to send message to google hangout using the above API(Code)**
I checked this link https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.onMessageReceived

In that sendMessage(message) available, how can i implement that method to my C#  code.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 6):

The Hangouts API is only valid for Hangout Apps that are running inside a Hangout Video Call. It is meant for app-to-app communication and not for external processes to be able to communicate with a Hangout App.

Hangout Apps can only be written in JavaScript, since they are run inside the browser.

If you are trying to send a message to someone via a Hangout Text Chat - this currently isn't possible. You may wish to open an issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/ to make sure Google is aware of the desire and use-cases for this feature.

Comment: This is bad of Google, really rally bad.